# How to hide a wet spot during massage?

Tags: clothing

When getting a massage, sometimes the way the massagist touches my body results in spontaneous and unwanted arousal, which then might result in a visible wet spot on the underwear. (Not ejaculaton, this is easy enough to control, it's rather the Cowper’s fluid over which I have much less control.)

**Important to mention**: this is not an erotic massage. It's performed by a professional masseur or masseuse. (Both might cause me such reaction, it doesn't matter and it's not due to sexual attraction.)

I did try to avoid it by various methods (thinking of totally unrelated things during the massage, relieving myself shortly before, etc.) but failed, it appears to be purely physical reaction of the body.

My question is: when such thing happens, is there a way to hide the wet spot? So far when it happened the massagist didn't show any reaction at all, as expected, but it was very embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fiddling with plastic wrap and tape, get a pack of panty liners (choose the thin kind with a waterproof layer and do not buy the more bulky menstrual pads) and stick that into your underwear.

It will be more comfortable to the skin than foil, will actually soak up the leakage and the sticky tape will prevent it from slipping - because that’s exactly what these things were designed for: to catch small unwanted amounts of liquid and protect your clothes. Pro tip: stay away from the scented ones.

On a different note:
A professional will be well aware that not all bodily reactions can be controlled all times and will simply ignore spontaneous erections or bits of leakage. (As long as it’s clear that you are also staying neutral and are not seeking some different kind of *relief*.)

Comment: Thanks, as a male it never occurred to me I can use such a thing. But are you sure that when having this in the underwear, it's not possible to detect it? If the massagist will notice such a thing, it will be more embarrassing than a wet spot. As for your last paragraph, you're correct that's what I experienced so far with all massagists.

Comment: It depends a bit on your choice of underwear and the liner in question. It’s hard to say off the cuff. But it’s probably way more convenient than other hacks and it should work well enough.

Comment: Well might be fine with black boxers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can contain the emission if you:

- wear a condom
- use waterproof underwear

Comment: Thanks, that's an intetesting idea. But won't the condom slip off? I never really tried to wear one when the penis is flaccid.

Comment: Well this is a Life Hack stack and my answer focuses on the problem, but IMO it would be better to train yourself not to respond when you know that the encounter is non-sexual, but self-improvement is off-topic.

Comment: I've tried to train myself and sometimes it's fine, but still not perfect, so try to figure ways to reduce damage when I fail to control it. Your idea is good (I would upvote if/when I'll have enough rep) but I just wonder what will happen if really trying it.

Comment: Other suggestions would be to use clingfilm, or incontinence underwear.

Comment: Thanks, clingfilm was already suggested in the other answer and looks like the best option so far, might give it a try. As for  incontinence underwear that's actually a diaper (for adults), like I said in comment to the other answer I thought about it too, but that would be easily visible and very embarassing. Guess I might say it's for medical condition, but still, this might be only a last resort.

Comment: You can get waterproof underwear that isn't padded, unlike a nappy (the UK term).

Comment: That's interesting, didn't know such thing exist, thought there is only the "pull up pants" for adults. I saw it does exist, though it's not cheap. Thanks again, this is indeed pretty much ideal. Care to add it to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**How to hide a wet spot during massage?**

An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.

If you can not physically prevent it, try tapping some thin plastic or Saran Wrap to the inside of your underwear. In other words, make yourself a homemade diaper.

Sounds childlike, but I bet you it will work!

Comment: I thought about diaper, but that would be easily visible and very embarassing, so ruled this idea out. Thin plastic wrap is something I didn't think about, and it might actually work. Thanks! :)